# Accessing an Excel file imported to R

Tags: r, excel

I have just started using R and imported my first Excel file named tblMainXmasFund. When I try running data(tblMainXmasFund) I get the following:

Warning message:
In data(tblMainXmasFund) : data set ‘tblMainXmasFund’ not found

The readxl package has been installed. When I try running library(readxl) I get:
Warning message:
package ‘readxl’ was built under R version 4.1.3 (My version of R is 4.1.2)

I'm guessing I have missed a necessary step but have no clue what it is. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to read the file with something like this:  `readxl::read_excel("tblMainXmasFund.xlsx")`

Comment: If you already imported your excel file (CSV? `.xlsx`?) into R and stored it in an object named `tblMainXmasFund`, then you don't need to use the `data(...)` command at all.

Comment: Dave2e: When I use readxl::read_excel("tblMainXmasFund.xlsx") I get Error: `path` does not exist: ‘tblMainXmasFund.xlsx’. However, when I insert the path it displays a list of the first 10 rows of data. Good progress!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
library(readxl)
tblMainXmasFund <- read_excel("Path_file/tblMainXmasFund.xls")
```

In `Path_file` write the address of your Excel file. Remember to use `/` to separate path and file name.

In this way, `tblMainXmasFund` is a "container" to your Excel file, if later in your code you have to do something with this data you can use only `tblMainXmasFund` to call it.

Comment: I tried the following.

Comment: Inuraghe, I tried this: library(readxl)
tblMainXmasFund <- read_excel("C:/Excel/For R/tblMainXmasFund.xlsx") and received this response: Error in read_excel("C:/Excel/For R/tblMainXmasFund.xlsx") : 
  could not find function "read_excel". What should I do next?

Comment: Have you installed package readxl? The code is install.packages(readxl)

Comment: I think I have readxl installed but am not certain. The following code works: readxl::read_excel("C:/Excel/For R/tblMainXmasFund.xlsx") and  <br/> my_data <- readxl::read_excel("C:/Excel/For R/tblMainXmasFund.xlsx")
sum(my_data$Amount). <br/> However, if I add library(readxl) to the code I get a warning that package ‘readxl’ was built under R version 4.1.3 , but when I run it a second time no warning appears. Does this confirm that readxl has been installed?

Comment: Yes, you have installed the library. You have to remember to run every library at every new session